# any way to get rxvt to recognize shift+tab?

Tags: rxvt

I'm simply trying to get shift+tab to be a recognized key sequence during my rxvt terminal sessions.  So I can map it to usefulness such as:

```
bindkey "\e[Z" reverse-menu-complete
```

But, based on my research, I'm pretty sure the answer is no.  Just want to make sure.

This is a hard limitation of rxvt?  (Is there a technical reason for this limitation?  Or just an unsupported feature?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't get it to emit that either, although strangely enough, the rxvt source code (as shipped with Cygwin) does appear to have support for it:

```
case XK_Tab:
  if (shft)
    STRCPY(kbuf, "\033[Z");
  else {
    ...
```

Anyway, rxvt development stopped eight years ago. Try its successor, [rxvt-unicode](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html), aka urxvt, where this does work. If you're on Cygwin or MSYS and you were using rxvt without an X server, which urxvt does require, try [mintty](http://mintty.googlecode.com).

Comment: fantastic answer, thanks.  Any chance you could post the link to the rxvt source code?

Comment: You're welcome. Here's the link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/rxvt/files/rxvt-dev/2.7.10/rxvt-2.7.10.tar.gz.
Out of curiosity: which platform are you running it on?